# set time in a calendar (android)

Tags: android, timepicker

I'd like to make a app who changes me the airplane mode. I have a timepicker and a calendar. Now I want to set the time from the tp into the cal. I have made 2 toast to control the time from both objects. The toast from the tp shows me the right time (f. e. 13:04) but the calendar object has after the "setting" the wrong time (11:12)
I've read that the time is setted just if methodeds like *getTimeinMillis()* are called so added this method but it isn't still working . Thanks for your answers

```
Button b;
Button b2;
TimePicker tp;
Calendar cal;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    b = (Button)(findViewById(R.id.button1));
    tp = (TimePicker)(findViewById(R.id.timePicker1));
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    b2 = (Button)(findViewById(R.id.button2));

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"TimePicker "+ tp.getCurrentHour()+":"+tp.getCurrentMinute(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,tp.getCurrentHour());
                    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,tp.getCurrentMinute());
                    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
                    cal.getTimeInMillis();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Calendar "+ cal.HOUR_OF_DAY+":"+cal.MINUTE, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: can you tell me which timezone set in your phone just for info ......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the fields correctly, but you don't query the fields of a calendar like that. What you are doing there is printing the int value of the HOUR_OF_DAY field on the calendar class which has the value 11 ([See here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY)).

The method getTimeinMillis will just return the number of miliseconds since Epoch (Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT). There's no need for it to be there.

use:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Calendar "+ cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) +":"+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: thanks alot I allready thought that it would be a stupid mistake ;)

Answer (score 4):

The answer provided by Nuno Gonçalves will solve your problem.  However, it is nicer to use the date/time formatters provided by [android.text.format.DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html) when you are displaying dates/times to users.  This way the information shows up in the manner that the user is expecting (e.g. 12-hour vs. 24-hour time, etc.).

So, something like this:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Calendar: "
                         + DateFormat.getTimeFormat(this).format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to focus on that. :) +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following calendar implementation :

`Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());`